# How to compare button options against array then disable it using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

**I want to disable a button or change its class if it is not a valid option.**

I am using this for product options on an eCommerce site.

I have 3 arrays.  The first 2 i use to create the button combinations.  I am thinking I can use the last array to compare and decide if the option is valid. 
 If it isn't valid I would like for the button to be disabled.

(ie: if medium or large option is selected then green is disabled or grayed out because it is not a valid option combination)

[Sample Image of buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8W0Y.png)

```
myArraySize = ['small', 'medium', 'large'];
myArrayColor = ["blue", "red", "green"];
myArrayValidOptions = ["small-blue", "medium-blue", "large-blue", "small-red", "medium-red", "large-red", "small-green"];
```

Here is an example on codepen.  please somebody work their magic.  I really appreciate it.  I am really new to jquery/javascript and would like to get this working.

https://codepen.io/cliebich/pen/gRdKOq

Comment: What is your specific problem or question? Take some time to read [ask]

Comment: 1) your codepen is broken. 2) SO is not a code writing service. It is expected that you try to write some code to accomplish your goal. Then ask a question here on what you are having a problem doing. "Do you haz teh codez?" is not a valid question for this site.

Comment: I was playing around on the codepen I linked (caught me in between changes and the code was broken).  I reverted to the original working code at the state where I am stumped. If you could take a crack at it now that would be great. I have been able to google this sort of thing until now.  This one has me stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```js
myArraySize = ['small', 'medium', 'large'];
myArrayColor = ["blue", "red", "green"];
myArrayValidOptions = [
    "small-blue",
    "medium-blue",
    "large-blue",
    "small-red",
    "medium-red",
    "large-red",
    "small-green"
];

var result = $(".specOptions");
result.html("");

var result2 = $(".specOptions2");
result2.html("");

for (var i = 0; i < myArraySize.length; i++) {
    result.append(
        '<a class="btn btn-default btn-variant" name="myArraySize" data-value="' +
        myArraySize[i] +
        '" > ' +
        myArraySize[i] +
        "</a>"
    );
}
for (var i = 0; i < myArrayColor.length; i++) {
    result2.append(
        '<a class="btn btn-default btn-variant" name="myArrayColor" data-value="' +
        myArrayColor[i] +
        '" > ' +
        myArrayColor[i] +
        "</a>"
    );
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".specOptions a, .specOptions2 a").click(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("disabled"))
            return;

        var theSelector = $(this).parent().attr("class");

        var value = $(this).data("value"); // value of checkbox
        $("." + theSelector + " a").removeClass("btn-primary"); // clear checkboxes in same group (mimic radio behavior)
        $("." + theSelector + ' a[data-value="' + value + '"]').addClass("btn-primary"); // check all checkboxes with same value

        if (this.name === "myArraySize") {
            $("a[name='myArrayColor']").each(function() {
                var color = $(this).data("value");
                if (myArrayValidOptions.indexOf(value + "-" + color) < 0)
                   $(this).addClass("disabled").removeClass("btn-primary");
                else
                   $(this).removeClass("disabled");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.btn{margin:3px;}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="prodOptions">
    <div class="specOptions">
    </div>
    <div class="specOptions2"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks h77, I appreciate you spending the time on this.  your example didn't do what I needed it to do (probably my terrible job of explaining what I needed). I ended up figuring it out although not very elegant.  Here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/cliebich/pen/rwZKbd

Comment: OK. I thought it was both ways. I guess commenting out the 2nd part of the if block is what you wanted.